# Create list of list of numbers. If sorting is wrong a new sublist should be created

Tags: python, sublist

a) Input is list of numbers

```
i/p = > [2,5,1,4,7,3,1,2,3]
```

b) output should be sorted sublists

```
o/p = > [[2,5],[1,4,7],[3],[1,2,3]]
```

Comment: Ok, it seems you need to make a list of sorted sublists. What have you tried so far?

Comment: This is not really a question, please provide text.

Comment: @Parag Ghodaskar you saw my answer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Algorithm**

```
input = [2,5,1,4,7,3,1,2,3]

output = [[]]
for idx,val in enumerate(input):
    if idx > 0 and input[idx-1] > input[idx]:
        output.append([val])
    else:
        output[-1].append(val)

print output
```

Output is

```
[[2, 5], [1, 4, 7], [3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

**Explanation of the algorithm in words:**

Create an output list with an empty sublist. Enumerate over the input list. If the previous element (if one exists) is not bigger than the actual element add the element to the last sublist of the output. If it's bigger create a new sublist in output and add it to this new sublist.

Comment: @ParagGhodaskar added the explanation of the algorithm. Did you understand it?

Comment: yes kordi.I was trying this with bubble sort,2>5,5>1 false so remove 2,5 from original list and continue with sorting remaining list.how could we do this?

Comment: @ParagGhodaskar You don't have do sort anything. Cause if sort is wrong create a new sublist. Is it that I should just remove the elements from the input list, which are added to the sublist.

Comment: no kordi the solution you provide is exactly what i need.Just can we do it with bubble sort.ex: 5 > 1  put 2,5 in sublist and proceed with remaining list,sort again till 7 and so on.

Answer (score -1):

Another Solution:

```
def sortedsublist():
'''create sorted sublist from the given list'''
    inputl = []
    sortedl = []
    subl = []
    inputl = [7,8,9,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,1]
    for i in range(len(inputl)):
    try:
    if inputl[i] <= inputl[i+1]:
        subl.append(inputl[i])
    else:
        subl.append(inputl[i])
        sortedl.append(subl)
        subl= []    
     except IndexError:
        subl.append(inputl[i])
        sortedl.append(subl)
        subl = []
    print sortedl   
    return
if __name__="main":
    sortedsublist()
```